# Multiple inner join with multiple where clause

Tags: inner-join, where-clause

i want to ask how to do multiple inner join with multiple where clause

for exemlpe i want to select records from  tab1, tab2, tab3 and tab4 
and make inner join between reuslt tables

thank you

Comment: Hello, can you please give us samples of your tables structures ? Also, did you try to search for "INNERJOIN" documentation on internet ?

Comment: Can you show what you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

U can try to either inner join tab1 to tab4 and then select the rows or you could try something like:
SELECT * FROM (SELECT rowsFromTab1 FROM Tab1 WHERE whereClauseForTab1) INNER JOIN (SELECT rowsFromTab2 FROM Tab2 WHERE whereClauseForTab2)